# Fix space for the punctuation (like comma and period) by using listings.sty

Tags: spacing, listings

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=java, emph={},
    mathescape=false, escapechar=`,
%   backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    commentstyle=\color{darkgray},
    keywordstyle=\color{darkergray}\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\normalsize\sffamily,
    numberstyle=\normalsize\sffamily,
    emphstyle=\bfseries,
    numbers=left, stepnumber=1,
    numberblanklines=false,
    %numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbersep=3pt,
    frame=none, framexleftmargin=3pt, framexrightmargin=0pt,
    %xleftmargin=15pt, xrightmargin=4pt,
    columns=flexible, breaklines=true,
    showspaces=false, showstringspaces=false, showtabs=false, tabsize=2,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    morekeywords={grammar, lambda, define, car, cdr, cons, null?, list,
    let, fork, lock, unlock  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none]
"Nail is missing..."
"For want of a nail, the shoe was lost."
"For want of a shoe, the horse was lost."
"For want of a horse, the rider was lost."
"For want of a rider, the message was lost."
"For want of a message, the battle was lost."
"For want of a battle, the kingdom was lost."
"And all for the want of a horseshoe nail."
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Space before punctuation like period and comma displayed as uneven, I'm already aware that if we change `columns=fullflexible` will solve the issue, but some reason I should use the `columns=flexible`, but need to fix the punctuation are in the standard way? Is it possible to fix? Please advise...

Need to fix the spacing issue atleast for `comma` only, `period` is an optional ...

Comment: Switching to a monospaced font would be my recommendation... typographically speaking...

Comment: Is there a reason you're typing text into a code type environment like listings?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, it's my Professor's requirement....